# Determine if $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix} xy\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^4}) & (x,y) \ne (0,0)\\ 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{matrix}\right.$ continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, polar-coordinates

Determine if $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
xy\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^4}) & (x,y) \ne (0,0)\\ 
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

I have tried looking at different directions, polar coordinates, and the squeeze rule.

With the polar, I got a function that I don't know what to do with, and with the squeeze rule I always have $x$ and $y$.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: If $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, then $|f(x,y)|\leqslant|xy|$. What else do you need?

Comment: If I bound it with $|xy|$ is it ok? I know that if I bound a function, for example, with $|\frac{x}{y}|$ it can be anything, so what is the different? Thanks!

Comment: Since $|x|,|y|\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $|xy|\leqslant x^2+y^2$.

Comment: And than $x,y \to 0$, so by the squeeze rule $f \to 0$?

Comment: When checking if $xy\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^4}\right) \to 0, ~$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, you can ignore the cosine factor, because it is bounded, (i.e. the cosine function is a bounded function).

Comment: I think I understand now. This is my first time working with 2 variables, so it still confuses me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let ${(x_n, y_n)}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$, such that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n, y_n) = (0, 0) \; .$$
Note that
$$
0 \leq \left| f(x_n,y_n) \right| \leq \left| x_n y_n \right|
$$
for each $n \in \mathbb N$.

By the squeeze theorem we see that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| f(x_n, y_n) \right| = 0 \; ,
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n, y_n) = 0 = f(0, 0)\; ,
$$
so $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove that $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, so you should show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0).$$
By definition on $f$, you have that $$f(0,0)=0$$
and since that $$-1\leqslant \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{4}}\right)\leqslant 1$$
So, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}xy\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{4}}\right)=0.$$
Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.